# Cumulative Total Headcount Past 12 Months

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have the below measure which calculates the headcount. I would like to create a new measure which calculates the running total for the past 12 months.

TIA

```
Employee Count = 
VAR selectedDate = MAX('Date'[Date])
RETURN
SUMX('Table1',
VAR employeeStartDate =  [DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT]
VAR employeeEndDate = [DATE_OF_LEAVING]
RETURN IF(employeeStartDate <= selectedDate && 
OR(employeeEndDate >= selectedDate, employeeEndDate=BLANK()
),1,0)
)
```

Comment: what result do you when you use the measure you have provided? could you provide and example of what you expect and what you get?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want something that is called Moving Annual Total (MAT). Assuming that you have a Date table (Calendar) you can use the following pattern. Replace the [Sales Amount] measure with your favorite one.

```
Sales MAT :=
CALCULATE(
    [Sales Amount],
    DATESINPERIOD(
        'Date'[Date],
        MAX( 'Date'[Date] ),
        -1,
        YEAR
    )
)
```

Check for MAT here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/standard-time-related-calculations/